# SQL Join and get null output for absent record

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, sql-server-2019

How can I get the output from this below two table (in SQL Server 2019):

[image]

In here, just **need to cross check the Record ID column between table A an Table B.
If record id is absent in Table B then need to insert 'NULL' into the output table** .

We have tried this below Query but  not giving proper output.

How can we get faster and accurate output.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.RecordId,A.LineNo, B.Value
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.RecordId = B.RecordId
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more details about "but it take long time to execute"   and about  "not giving proper output" .   How long is "a long time "?, and what is expected?      And what is not "proper output"? what is expected ?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: It's not giving proper output.

Comment: Ur example for expected doesnt make sense. First you want AA then NULL for RecordID100. But it always exists in Table B. You have to specifiy what you actualy want.

Comment: Considering your statement "If record id is absent in Table B then need to insert 'NULL' into the output table" ALL your rows will have a match in Table B!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking a guess on this from the data - but I think this is what you want.

From the looks of it, you fundamentally want a LEFT JOIN from TableA to TableB (as you have) but not just on RecordID - it also needs LineNo.

However, LineNo doesn't exist in TableB. Therefore you can create it using a window function ROW_NUMBER() e.g.,

```
SELECT [ID], 
    [RecordID], 
    [Value], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [RecordID] ORDER BY [ID]) AS [LineNo]
FROM [TableB]
```

The above creates the following results.

```
ID  RecordID  Value  LineNo
1   100       AA     1
2   102       BB     1
3   102       BC     2
4   103       CC     1
```

Now, for your final answer, do a similar LEFT JOIN but instead of TableB in your join, use the sub-query with the additional column - and then include the additional column in the join e.g.,

```
SELECT [A].[ID], [A].[RecordId], [A].[LineNo], [B].[Value]
FROM [TableA] A
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT [ID], 
        [RecordID], 
        [Value], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [RecordID] ORDER BY [ID]) AS [LineNo]
     FROM TableB
    ) B ON A.[RecordId] = B.[RecordId] AND A.[LineNo] = B.[LineNo]
```

Here's a [DB_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=98d1de9e29f380e15a8e01bb8570856f) with data and results.

Edit: tweaked typos - also note that LineNo seems to be a reserved keyword, so I have added square brackets around all of them.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It's working fine.